# Python - lookup value in dataframe and return random corresponding value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

df1 has a lot of NaN values.

I have compiled df2 with all unique values for code and name.

I need to replace the NaN code values in df1 with a random code value from df2 where df1 and df2 match on name.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','name','code'])
df1.ID = [1,2,3,4]
df1.name = ['A','A','B','B']
df1.code = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','code'])
df2.name = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
df2.code = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

df1
[image: df1]

df2
[image: df2]

example result
[image: example result]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `random.sample` and pas `2` after joining the values for each group into a list. Then, merge back into the initial dataframe, `explode` the list and `drop_duplicates()`

```
import random
df2 = df2.groupby('name')['code'].apply(lambda x: random.sample(list(x), 2)).reset_index()
df3 = df1[['ID', 'name']].merge(df2).explode('code').drop_duplicates(['name', 'code']).reset_index(drop=True)
df3['ID'] = np.flatnonzero(df3['ID']) + 1

Out[1]: 
   ID name code
0   1    A    d
1   2    A    a
2   3    B    h
3   4    B    f
```

Comment: For some reason .explode is not working for me.

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @BD12 you’ll have to upgrade your version of pandas

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary where the keys are *names* and the values are the possible code, then for each name in *df1* sample from the corresponding value:

```
import random

lookup = df2.groupby('name')['code'].apply(list).to_dict()

df1['code'] = df1['code'].fillna(pd.Series([random.choice(lookup[name]) for name in df1['name']],
                           index=df1.index))
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
   ID name code
0   1    A    b
1   2    A    b
2   3    B    g
3   4    B    g
```

If sample without replacement is needed you could do:

```
lst = [s for k, g in df1.groupby('name', as_index=False) for s in random.sample(lookup[k], len(g))]
df1['code'] = df1['code'].fillna(pd.Series(lst, index=df1.index))

print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
   ID name code
0   1    A    d
1   2    A    a
2   3    B    e
3   4    B    h
```